# How to troubleshoot socket connection from Asterisk

Tags: c, asterisk

I wrote a module for asterisk that needs to communicate to a service request information an return it, but for some reason my socket does not connect at all. When I telnet to the service it works fine, but I can not figure out why the it returns a -1 in the module

This is the code in my module

```
int SocketQuery(char buffer[BUFFSIZE],char *qrystr){
            int sock;
            struct sockaddr_in eserver;
            int sockres = 0;
            unsigned char receiving = 1;

            memset(sendbuff,0,sizeof(sendbuff));
            /* Create the TCP socket */
            if ((sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)) < 0) {
              ast_log(LOG_ERROR,"Failed to create socket for LCRROUTER");
              return -1;
            }
            /* Construct the server sockaddr_in structure */
            memset(&eserver, 0, sizeof(eserver));       /* Clear struct */
            eserver.sin_family = AF_INET;                  /* Internet/IP */
            eserver.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(IP);  /* IP address */
            eserver.sin_port = htons(port);       /* server port */
            /* Establish connection */
            ast_log(LOG_NOTICE,"LCRROUTER - Connection to %s on port %s\n", IP, port);
            sockres = connect(sock,
                        (struct sockaddr *) &eserver,
                        sizeof(eserver));
            if (sockres < 0) {
              ast_log(LOG_ERROR,"LCRROUTER - Failed to connect with server on %s:%s. Error Code %d", IP,port,sockres);
              return -1;
            }
```

`sockres` returns -1. Do I miss something?

Comment: My problem was with the port. Although it printed correctly in the Debug, it was a char, so I had to use `atoi(port)` to fix my problem. Noob mistake :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
 tcpdump port YOUR_PORT_HERE -v -s0
```

In that form it will show you all packets sent via socket.